# Norm on cartesian product of normed spaces

Tags: normed-spaces

On Peter Lax's book 'Functional Analysis', there is an exercise to show that $|(z,u)|=(|z|^2+|u|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a norm in the cartesian product of two normed spaces, $(Z,|\cdot |)$ and $(U,|\cdot |)$.

The positivity and homogeneity are very straightforward, but I can't seem to manage the subadditivity of it.

The only things that came to mind to try and solve it was using the subadditivity of the already defined norms and I also noticed the concave properties of $\cdot ^2$ and $\cdot^\frac{1}{2}$, but those fail to produce anything helpful.

Could anyone share how this is meant to be shown? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $|(z, u)| = |(|z|, |u|)|_{2}$, where $|\cdot|_2$ is the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with due to the Mason's comment.

Let $|\cdot|_2$ be the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $|(x,y)|_2=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $(Z,|\cdot|_z)$ and $(U,|\cdot|_u)$ be the two normed linear spaces and $(Z\oplus U,|\cdot|)$ the supposed normed linear space with $|(z,u)|=(|z|_z^2+|u|_u^2)^{1/2}$. To show subadditivity of the norm $|\cdot|$ note that:

$$|(z_1,u_1)+(z_2,u_2)|=|(z_1+z_2,u_1+u_2)|=|(|z_1+z_2|_z,|u_1+u_2|_u)|_2$$$$\leq|(|z_1|_z+|z_2|_z,|u_1|_u+|u_2|_u)|_2\leq|(|z_1|_z,|u_1|_u)|_2+|(|z_2|_z,|u_2|_u)|_2$$$$=|(z_1,u_1)|+|(z_2+u_2)|$$

where the first inequality is due to the subadditivity of the preestablished z- and u-norm and the second inequality due to the subadditivity of the Euclidean norm.